# How Can I Transfer My fiddle Code To My Website?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

On my website I have a drop-down reservation form. On my form I wanted to add extra buttons to click so a separate form can come up.

I used jsfiddle to help me create the code and this is the code that I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5RW6/embedded/

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id=nav>
    <ul>
        <ul>

            <label id=form1-control>Address</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <label id=form2-control>Airport</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <label id=form3-control>Landmark/Hotel</label>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id=forms>
    <div id=form1>
        <form method=post action="">
            <label>Street Address:</label>
            <input type=text name=name>
            <tr>
                <p>
                    <td class="width:110px; height:15px">
                        <label>City:
                            <input type=text id=city name=city>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width:70px; height:15px">
                        <p>
                            <label>State:
                                <input type="text" id="state" name="state">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <label>Zip Code:
                                <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip">
                        </p>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Date <span class=""> * </span> 
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="calendar" name="calendar" style="height:25px" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Time</label>
                <select id="time" name="time" style="height:25px; width:55px">
                    <option>--</option>
                    <option>01</option>
                    <option>02</option>
                    <option>03</option>
                    <option>04</option>
                    <option>05</option>
                    <option>06</option>
                    <option>07</option>
                    <option>08</option>
                    <option>09</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                </select>
                <select id="time2" name="time2" style="height:25px; width:55px">
                    <option selected="">--</option>
                    <option>00</option>
                    <option>01</option>
                    <option>02</option>
                    <option>03</option>
                    <option>04</option>
                    <option>05</option>
                    <option>06</option>
                    <option>07</option>
                    <option>08</option>
                    <option>09</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                    <option>13</option>
                    <option>14</option>
                    <option>15</option>
                    <option>16</option>
                    <option>17</option>
                    <option>18</option>
                    <option>19</option>
                    <option>20</option>
                    <option>21</option>
                    <option>22</option>
                    <option>23</option>
                    <option>24</option>
                    <option>25</option>
                    <option>26</option>
                    <option>27</option>
                    <option>28</option>
                    <option>29</option>
                    <option>30</option>
                    <option>31</option>
                    <option>32</option>
                    <option>33</option>
                    <option>34</option>
                    <option>35</option>
                    <option>36</option>
                    <option>37</option>
                    <option>38</option>
                    <option>39</option>
                    <option>40</option>
                    <option>41</option>
                    <option>42</option>
                    <option>43</option>
                    <option>44</option>
                    <option>45</option>
                    <option>46</option>
                    <option>47</option>
                    <option>48</option>
                    <option>49</option>
                    <option>50</option>
                    <option>51</option>
                    <option>52</option>
                    <option>53</option>
                    <option>54</option>
                    <option>55</option>
                    <option>56</option>
                    <option>57</option>
                    <option>58</option>
                    <option>59</option>
                </select>
                <select id="time3" name="time3" style="height:25px; width:55px">
                    <option selected="">--</option>
                    <option>AM</option>
                    <option>PM</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="width:110px;">
                            <label style="font-size:13px">Passenger #: <span class='error'></span>
                            </label>
                            <td class="width30">
                                <input type="number" id="passengers" name="passengers" style="width:50px;margin:3px">
                            </td>
                        </td>
                        <td class="width:70px; height:15px">
                            <label style="font-size:13px">Luggage #:</label>
                            <td class="width30">
                                <input type="number" id="luggages" name="luggages" style="width:50px; margin:3px">
                            </td>
                        </td>
                        <td class="width:50px;" colspan="2">
                            <label style="font-size:13px">Car Seat:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="width30">
                            <input type="number" id="seat" name="seat" style="width:50px; margin:3px">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                    </tr>
                    </td>
                </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id=form2>
        <form method=post action="">
            <td class="width:110px; height:15px">
                <label style="font-size:13px">Airport Name: <span class='error'></span>
                </label>
                <td class="width30">
                    <input type="text" id="airport" name="airport" class="input85" style="width:110px; margin:10px" value="" />
                </td>
            </td>
            <td class="width:70px">
                <label style="font-size:13px">Airline/Code:</label>
                <td class="width30">
                    <input type="text" id="airline" name="airline" class="input85" style="width:60px; margin:10px" value="" />
                </td>
            </td>
            <td class="width:50px" colspan="2">
                <label style="font-size:13px">Flight #:</label>
            </td>
            <td class="width:30">
                <input type="text" id="fnumber" name="fnumber" class="input85" style="width:40px;margin:10px" value="" />
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="width:110px;">
                        <label style="font-size:13px">Passenger #: <span class='error'></span>
                        </label>
                        <td class="width30">
                            <input type="number" id="passengers" name="passengers" style="width:50px;margin:3px">
                        </td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width:70px;">
                        <label style="font-size:13px">Luggage #:</label>
                        <td class="width30">
                            <input type="number" id="luggages" name="luggages" style="width:50px; margin:3px">
                        </td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width:50px;" colspan="2">
                        <label style="font-size:13px">Car Seat:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="width30">
                        <input type="number" id="seat" name="seat" style="width:50px; margin:3px">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                </tr>
                </td>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id=form3>
        <form method=post action="">
            <label>Full Address:</label>
            <input type=text name=name style=width:280px>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**QUESTION**
How can I transfer the code correctly to my website to everything can work?

Comment: Carefully copy/paste?

Comment: Do you have an actual problem with transferring the code correctly to your website? There isn't anything magic about it. you just... copy and paste it, then make sure the script references are in the right order.

Comment: @JasonP , I did copy and paste but it didn't transfer correctly onto my website.

Comment: @KevinB on jsfiddle it works perfectly fine, once you click the buttons, the form comes up. On my website, I put everything in the right order, but the form is all out

Comment: Ok, well, what about it didn't transfer correctly? what errors are occuring? what did you do to try to fix them?

Comment: Did you check your javascript error console and network tab for errors?

Comment: And at least start using quotes when giving attributes a value.

Comment: @KevinB The buttons did not come up on my form. I tried creating a whole new code without jsfiddle, rechecked everything, and it still didn't work.

Comment: @JasonP yes I did, everything was perfectly fine

Comment: Is your css in the correct place and not being overridden by some other css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of this depends on which browser you are using, but, from Safari or Chrome on the Mac:

- Use the embedded link you have above
- Click on result
- Bring up the context menu over one of the buttons and select `inspect element`.
- Find the `<html>` tag within an `<iframe>` tag

  [image: Html element under iframe]
- Bring up the context menu for the html element and select `copy as html`

  [image: Context menu]

This should copy the full html doc result allowing you to paste it into the editor of your choice.

It will have an extra stylesheet reference that you will probably want to remove:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
```